# Add elements to arry in powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to simply add some numbers to an array and then sort them via powershell, however, the following code seems to be wrong

```
$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ($Name in $VMName) {
    $Tokens = $Name.Split(".")
    $myArray.Add($Tokens[$Tokens.Count-1])
}
Write-Host($myArray | Sort-Object)
```

The error is

```
+     $myArray.Add($Tokens[$Tokens.Count-1])
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

How can I fix that?

The variable `$Name` is something like `101.u18.uab.14` or `103.win10.template` or `102.win7.pink.18` and so on. Each `$Name` has some `.` symbols and I want to tokenize them and get the last element for each of them. So, in this example, I want to see a sorted `14 18 template`.

UPDATE:

The provided methods seems to be incorrect.

1- This method by Steven

```
$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ($Name in $VMName) {
    $Tokens = $Name.Split(".")
    [Void]$myArray.Add($Tokens[-1])
}
```

shows this error

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\get_ip_list.ps1:20 char:5
+     [Void]$myArray.Add($Tokens[-1])
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

2- This method by Santiago

```
$myArray = [Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
Foreach ($Name in $VMName) {
    [Void]$myArray.Add($Name.Split(".")[-1])
}
```

Shows the following error

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\get_ip_list.ps1:19 char:5
+     [Void]$myArray.Add($Name.Split(".")[-1])
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupportedException
```

If I have missed your point in the above codes, please let me know.

Comment: [1] you are using an _arraylist_, not an _array_. [*grin*] ///// [2] are you trying to add the part of `$Tokens` at the end of the split output? have you tried using `$LastToken = $Name.Split(".")[-1]` and then adding that instead?

Comment: That reduced the number of statements. Thanks.

Comment: I guess to give you a correct answer we need to understand what `$Name` is so `$Name.GetType()` and also we need to see an example of what `$Name` contains in order to understand better if your `split` method is actually doing what you want it to do.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Please see the updated post.

Comment: @mahmood - you are quite welcome! glad to have helped a little ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the first line from the error.  However it looks like you are simply trying to add the last elements from the `$Tokens` array.  In that case you don't need to reference the index like that, below should work:

```
$myArray = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
Foreach ($Name in $VMName) {
    $Tokens = $Name.Split(".")
    [Void]$myArray.Add($Tokens[-1])
}
```

Notice the addition of `[Void]` this will stop the `.Add()` method from returning the index number it just added to.

Also note you can create array list objects using casting like:

```
$myArray = [Collections.ArrayList]@()
```

**Update to Address Continued Errors:**

The only thing I can think of to cause the error "Collection was of a fixed size." is if you've previously type constrained the variable.

Example:

```
[String[]]$myArray = @()

# Posibly a whole bunch of other things happening maybe in the console or IDE.

$myArray = [Collections.ArrayList]@()
$myArray.Add('something')
```

Results:

```
Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."
At line:1 char:1
+ $myArray.Add('something')...
```

In this case they type of the `$myArray` will not change to `[Collections.ArrayList]`. The problem will be transparent up until you try to use the `.Add()` method that won't work. This is because an array list is easily and therefore silently cast back to a `[String[]]` or `[Object[]]`.

Note: If you were to run `$myArray.IsFixedSize` it would return "True".

My guess as to what's happening; at some point while developing your code or perhaps in the larger script, `$myArray` got type constrained, and stuck in the scope.  This can definitely happen especially given the scope overlap in IDE's like PowerShell's ISE, and I think it happens in VSCode as well.  If this is part of a larger script look for instances of `$myArray` to see if it's indeed type constrained and make corrections as needed.  Otherwise a simply restarting your session might do the trick.

Comment: I get `Exception calling "Add" with "1" argument(s): "Collection was of a fixed size."` The variable $Name is like `101.u18.uab.14` or `102.temple`.

Comment: OK I was able to fix that by `$LastToken = $Name.Split(".")[-1]` and `$myArray += $LastToken`.

Comment: @mahmood this `$myArray +=` is for `System.Array` not for collections and you definitely don't want that if you want performance. You can also use `[Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()` and you don't even need to save the in a variable before adding to the list, simply `[Void]$myArray.Add($Name.Split(".")[-1])` should work fine.

Comment: I have updated the post for the replies about using `.Add`. Please let me know if I wrote the code that you intended to state here.

Comment: Well, let's find out if the array is a fixed size? Run `$myArray.IsFixedSize` in the for each. If it returns true then we know.

Comment: Yup I think you're right on point, I didn't know about that, learnt something new :D

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, not sure how could you be getting that error unless the `array` we're looping through is actually something different. [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67248446/4749264) should work fine, I'll put this code below just to show that the results we get are the ones you expect:

```
$col = [Collections.Generic.List[String]]::new()

$vmName = @(
    '101.u18.uab.14'
    '103.win10.template'
    '102.win7.pink.18'
)

ForEach($name in $vmName)
{
    $col.Add($name.Split('.')[-1])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry I couldn't resist.

Comment: @Steven no problem, I actually have an ocd for spaces LOL

Comment: Check out my update. I think I have a potential cause of the error.

Comment: Right. I got it. Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

if you want absolutly use array you can simply do it :

```
$Array=@()

$VMName | %{
 $Value=($_.Split('.'))[-1]
 $Array+= $Value
}

$Array| sort
```

Otherwise you can simply do it :

```
$VMName | %{($_.Split('.'))[-1]} | sort
```